# Evaluate function entrywise on high dimensional array

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation

I have defined a function $f$ from number to number. I want to tell Mathematica to apply that function to each entry of a high dimensional array $A$, to get a new array $f(A)$ in the same form of $A$. Mathematica automatically does that for simple functions like sine, powers, logarithms, etc. How do I do it for my defined functions?

Comment: You may want to look at [`Map[f, expr, levelspec]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) as in the documentation.

Comment: Also, lookup `Listable`.

Comment: @yohbs Listable is exactly what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the attribute [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) on the function.

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
```

Then it will auto-thread over arrays:

```
f[{1, 2, 3}]
(* {f[1], f[2], f[3]} *)
```

`Sin`, `Cos`, etc. also have this attribute:

```
Attributes[Sin]
(* {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected} *)
```